# Does accessing values in a foreach loop by reference work with custom Iterators, too?

Tags: php

If I write a class implementing [Iterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php), does this feature of [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) still work?

> In order to be able to directly modify array elements within the loop precede $value with &. In that case the value will be assigned by reference.

Perhaps more to the point, do I have to put '&' in my `Iterator`'s declaration of `current()`?

Answer (score 3):

You can't. On PHP 5.3.2, I get

> Fatal error: An iterator cannot be used with foreach by reference in *[file]* on line *[N]*